# Why is there empty output when running commands in this c code?

Tags: c, pipe, stderr

I have this function that executes a command

```
int cmd2(char * const *cmd, char * std_out)
{
    char tmp[4096];
    int pipefds[2], r, status, x; 
    pid_t pid;

    if (pipe(pipefds) == -1){
        return -1;
    }
    if ( (pid = fork()) == -1){
        return -1;
    }
    if (pid == 0)
    {
        dup2(pipefds[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        dup2(piepfds[1], STDERR_FILENO);
        close(pipefds[0]);
        close(pipefds[1]);
        execvp(cmd[0] , cmd);
    }
    else
    {
        close(pipefds[1]);
        x = read(pipefds[0], tmp, 4096);
        printf("Got %d bytes\n",x);
        wait(NULL); 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

the error message that should be outputted

```
┌──(kali㉿kali)-[~/]
└─$ ./wow  
zsh: no such file or directory: ./wow
```

when running another c code that `fputs` a buffer into `stderr` it is display by the `cmd2` without any problems

I tried to redirect `stderr` to `stdout` using `2>&1` but this does not seem to have an effect

how to read any/all results from executing the command

Comment: It isn't clear what the error message has to do with your program. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: What exact command gives you empty output? A command can behave differently if stdout is a pipe or tty, for example.

Comment: @dimich you can see the command in the kali linux terminal in the question i used the same command

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. what isn't clear to you, you have the function that executes the command and the command it self in the terminal, the question is why don't i get the same text from the terminal in the compiled c code

Comment: It is not obvious, is it a result you expect from your program, or attempt to run non-existing binary or what? We can't guess what is `./wow`

Comment: @dimich `./wow` is a non-existing binary the goal is to create and error and read it with the code

Comment: Ah, maybe you expect the same output as `zsh` gives you for non-existing command? You won't get it because your `execvp()` fails silently. Your program should check return value for error and print its own message.

Comment: @dimich any hints on why it fails?

Comment: Because `./wow` doesn't exist. If you want error message from zsh, make `cmd` content as `{"zsh", "-c", "./wow", NULL}`.

Comment: You won't get error message for `execvp()` from stderr because your child process terminates after `execvp()` fails. Nothing writes to stderr in this case. Check results returned by functions: ` if (execvp(...) == -1) perror("execvp");` But `execvp()` never retuns on success, so `if` is not necessary. Just print error message right after calling `execvp()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you try running a non-existent command with `cmd2`, `execvp` will set `errno` and return. It will not print anything anywhere. *You* need to check `errno` and print the error. Something as simple as:

```
execvp(cmd[0], cmd);
perror(cmd[0]);
exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
```

should usually suffice. `zsh` does something like that when you try to run a non-existent command with it, that's why you see an error message.

Note however that it is the child process that prints the message. You discard child process output and only print its length. You need to do something about it if you want to see the message.